# Median larger than mean in a Weibull distribution in scipy.stats

Tags: density-function, skewness, median, weibull-distribution, scipy

I am going a bit crazy here...

When I plot a Weibull function with shape = 6 and scale = 145 using `exponweib.pdf(x, 1, 6, scale=145, loc=1)`, the results looks like this:

[image]

To my (rather limited) statistical knowledge this should be a right skewed PDF and therefore the median smaller than the mean.

*However*, scipy.stats tells me otherwise:
`exponweib.median(1, 6, scale=145)` returns 136.4 and `exponweib.mean(1, 6, scale=145)` returns 134.5.

I am pretty sure I am overlooking something rather obvious here. Can anybody point me to it, please?

Comment: You display a *left* skewed PDF in which the mean is clearly a little smaller than the median.  Are you perhaps viewing this plot in a mirror? :-)

Comment: @whuber :D So I apparently lack understanding of skewness. I was assuming this function cannot become zero but goes to infinity. That is what I would understand as right-skewed...

Comment: "Skewed" generically means asymmetrical. There are many forms skewness can take and various related measurements thereof.  One is the standardized third moment: when it's positive, the PDF *often* looks stretched towards positive values ("right skewed"); when negative, the PDF *often* looks stretched towards negative values (as in your case). Another is the difference between the mean and median: positive implies that overall, data above the median are a bit further above it than data below the median are below it--again an indication of being "stretched" or "pulled" towards positive numbers.

Comment: @whuber Thank you very much! The only remaining question is: How can I give you credit for your help? Do you want to add an answer? Maybe the question is also too trivial and I should delete it?

Comment: I appreciate the offer.  I don't think it's trivial and I believe there's room for a good answer that would define skewness and discuss its quantification more expansively than I have done here in the comments.

Comment: The Weibull is *mostly* right skew, but at large values of the shape parameter it can be left skew by first one and then the other of the popular measures of skewness (third moment and mean-median version of skewness).

As you increase  $k$ to $\approx 3.44$ the median passes the mean. At $k\approx 3.6$ the third moment crosses $0$, passing from positive to negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your results against those given by the [Meta.Numerics](http://www.meta-numerics.net/) library and got exactly the same values. A Weibull with shape parameter 6.0 has skewness -0.37.

If you look at the graphs of Weibull PDFs on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) for various shape parameters, you'll see that it's right-skewed for small values of the shape parameter, but left-skewed for large values of the shape parameter. The skewness crosses zero at a shape parameter of about 3.6. If you look at the skewness formula in the same article, you will see that it has terms with mixed signs, so it is certainly possible to get both positive and negative skewness depending on which terms predominate.

Finally, you can think in terms of hazard functions. A Weibull with shape parameter 1 is just an exponential, which has a constant hazard function and is strongly right-skewed (skewness 2). As you increase the shape parameter, you are making the hazard function rising, which is going to more heavily favor low values, even though the right tail still has to extend out to infinity. That must decrease the skewness relative to an exponential, and in fact, for high enough shape parameters, it eventually makes the skewness negative.